# Toad: Shortcut to change between Toad window and Help window

Tags: oracle, window, keyboard-shortcuts, toad

In Toad for Oracle, I click on menu "Help > Contents" to open the help window. Then I press alt+tab to return to the Toad window, but I doesn't return to the Toad window, it goes to other window. So I have to click (with the mouse) on the Toad window to select it. Then I press alt+tab to return to the help window, but I doesn't return to the help window, it goes to other window. So I have to click (with the mouse) on the help window to select it.

**Any shortcut to change from Toad window to help window, and viceversa?**

Comment: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/get-more-from-windows-7-alttab-app-switching-tricks-you-didnt-know-about/

Answer (score 0):

Alt+Tab switches between open applications. The help and main Toad window are lumped together as the same application for Alt+Tab purposes. Alt+ESC will do what you want. It switches between open windows although it's a bit more of a stretch to reach.

Comment: I have tried it: If I'm at the toad window, open the help window (help > contents), and press alt+esc, it doesn't takes me to the previusly visited window (toad window), it takes me to other of my opened windows. So I have to press alt+esc several times to reach the toad window. It is not confortable.

Alt+tab remembers the previusly visited window/application. Alt+esc doesn't.

Comment: As far as I can tell that's the only way to do it, unfortunately. It's definitely not as comfortable as Alt+Tab.